# STM32 MCU works well in debug with breakpoint, but fail in debug mode

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm using STM32F303 MCU. I used STM32CubeIDE to generated a simple project. In the project, it increases an **int data** by 1 in main() -> while() loop.

```
int data = 0;

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  while (1)
  {
      // HAL_Delay(20);
      data++;
  }
}
```

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PREDIV = RCC_PREDIV_DIV1;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

- If I run in debug mode and add a breakpoint at **data++** line, everything is fine. I can see that the **int data** increases in **Live Expressions**.
- However, if I remove the breakpoint, the **int data** will be **3145848 (always this same number)** immediately and the firmware stops.
- Also, the **HAL_Delay()** will cause firmware fails. So I commented it out.
- The firmware works well in NUCLEO development board.

I also checked:

- Power supply is good 3.3V.
- All enable pins are just GPIO
- vout and iout pins are ADC.
- I also reduced clock frequency to 48MHz, but it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler knows that after you have incremented the value once, the only thing you are going to do next is increment it again.  It is being helpful by saving time incrementing it all in one go rather than a little at a time.

If you don't want the compiler to be helpful like this, then you need to declare your counter volatile:

```
volatile int data = 0;
```

This tells the compiler to carry out each access to the variable one at a time in the exact order specified.

Comment: Problem solved. it's my MCU soldering issue. After replacing a new PCB, it works well

Comment: @StevenWang your statement makes no sense at all. How can a hardware change affect a purely in-software variable? You mistakenly took a coincidence for a solution.